# ngrx entity with ActionReducerMap in Lazy Loaded Module

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

Can `@ngrx/entity` be used with `ActionReducerMap<State>` in Lazy Loaded Module `StoreModule.forFeature<>()`.

When I use it, I get below error in browser console log.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at ngrx-entity.js:67
    at ngrx-store.js:1096
    at memoized (ngrx-store.js:1011)
    at defaultStateFn (ngrx-store.js:1051)
    at ngrx-store.js:1105
    at memoized (ngrx-store.js:1011)
    at ngrx-store.js:1096
    at memoized (ngrx-store.js:1011)
    at defaultStateFn (ngrx-store.js:1051)
    at ngrx-store.js:1105
```

Comment: Please do mention if more part of the source code is required to be posted to identity the problem as I have mentioned only those file which I think is relevant.

Comment: Please share the component in which you're consuming it (component + template)

Comment: @RafiHenig I have edit the question and added components and templates where I am consuming it.